Issue with wkhtmltopdf html/css rendering on localhost vs hosted in browser?
I am using wkhtmltopdf to simply render an html as a PDF. On my localhost the page looks as expected:
On LocalHost
However, on the browser the formatting is all over the place. What is the issue here?
On hosted website
The HTML Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='responsive.css') }}">
    <title>Things Left Said.</title>
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .page-title {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        // background-color: #f0f0f0;  /* Add a background color for better visibility */
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .editable-label {
        font-size: 18px !important;  /* Adjust the font size as needed */
    }
    ul p {
    font-size: 24px;  /* Adjust the font size as needed */
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page-title">
    <h1>In honor of {{firstName}} {{lastName}}.</h1>
  </div>
    <h1>Q & A.</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for i in range(0, prompt_data|length) %}
        <!-- Use a span for the editable label -->
        <div class="editable_lable">
            <span id="{{i}}" class="editable-label" contenteditable="false" id="editable_label">{{ prompt_data[i][0] }}</span>
      </div>
      <p id="textbox{{i}}" name="{{i}}">{{prompt_data[i][1]}}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <h1>Comments.</h1>
    {% for i in range(0, comments|length) %}
    <div class="comments">
      <span id="{{i}}">
        {{ comments[i].text }},
        {% if comments[i].author is not none and comments[i].author.strip()|length > 0 %}
          Author: {{ comments[i].author }},
        {% endif %}
        Time: {{ comments[i].timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}
      </span>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>Pictures.</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="pictures_container">
        {% for picture in pictures %}
            <div class="picture-item">
              <img src="{{ url_for('display_picture', picture_id=picture.id, _external=True) }}" alt="User Picture" class="pdf_picture" style="max-width: 595px; height: auto;">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>


I was curious if the styles.css was not getting loaded but I did not see an issue with this in the logs.
